# System integrity invocation error. 907135701

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, fido

Getting the error while integrating the Huawei FIDO bioAuth.

`E/HMSSDK_com.huawei.hms.support.api.fido.bioauthn.FingerprintManager: System integrity invocation error. 907135701:`

Comment: Do you fix this problem? i am getting this error code

Answer (score 0):

I found this, maybe helps
[Error Code 907135701](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-3-References/hms-error-code-V3)

1. Check whether your phone has Internet access.
2. Check whether the current app has been created and has applied for related services. If the fault persists, contact Huawei technical support.

Answer (score 0):

If the device is not rooted, but HMS is not the latest, please upgrade and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The 907135701 error indicates the app is not configured in the AppGallery Connect correctly.
Please go to AppGallery Connect, create project, turn on FIDO and other desired services using “Manage API tab”, create app, fill-in proper App Name, Package name, signing certificate SHA signature

[image]

[image]
Download and Integrate the agconnect-services.json file to the app (Place the file in the app directory)

Sign the app and run again. Make sure the HMS core is up to date.